# Google Maps API V3 DirectionsService not exact end point

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I'm having a problem with the DirectionsService.

I want to show a route to some place that doesn't have map, so, I made some pieces of the route "by hand" (JavaScript markers and polygons). The problem is present when I request the route from one direction to the intersection of a route (point with latitude and longitude), the route show by the DirectionsService doesn't end exactly in the point indicated. To visualize this I prepared a fiddle:

[Personalized route](http://jsfiddle.net/aleaniquilador/nC4wN/)

The expected end point is {-30.745418, -59.580419} (the intersection between the two roads), but Google traces the route much to the north. Trying different coordinate, the trace moves away to the south or east, but never in the point I want.

If I move the marker "B" to the coordinates with the mouse, the route traces correctly, but I cannot make it automatic. Can't figure out how make the route to the exact point or "drag" the marker by JavaScript.

Edit: Google fixed this problem in the new version of Google Maps API.

HTML:

```
<div id="lienzoMapa1" class="lienzoMapa" style="width:960px; height:600px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var infowindow;     
var mapa1;     
var marcadores1 = new Array();     
var rutas1 = new Array();     
var resultadosRutas1 = new Array();     
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();     
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({'draggable': true});      
var objetosMarcadores1 = new Array();     
function agregarIcono(imagen, latitud, longitud, html, ponerAlFrente) {
    //Agregamos un icono de ruta
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitud, longitud);
    var marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: mapa1,
        icon: imagen
    });
    if (ponerAlFrente === true) {
        marcador.setZIndex(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);
    }
    objetosMarcadores1.push(marcador);
    return marcador;
}
function inicializarMapa(identificador, marcadores, zoom, tipoMapa, habilitarInterfaz, rutas){
    var latitudLongitud = new google.maps.LatLng(marcadores[0][0] , marcadores[0][1]);
    var opcionesMapa = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: latitudLongitud,
        mapTypeId: tipoMapa,
        disableDefaultUI: habilitarInterfaz
    };
    mapa1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("lienzoMapa" + identificador), opcionesMapa);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(mapa1);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for (contador=0; contador < marcadores.length; contador++){
        var latitudLongitud = new google.maps.LatLng(marcadores[contador][0] , marcadores[contador][1]);
        agregarMarcador(latitudLongitud, mapa1, marcadores[contador][2], marcadores[contador][3], marcadores[contador][4]);
    }
    for (contador=0; contador < rutas.length; contador++){  
        agregarRuta(rutas[contador][0], rutas[contador][1]);    
    }   
} 
function agregarMarcador(latitudLongitud, mapa, titulo, contenido, icono){
    var opcionesMarcador = {        
        position: latitudLongitud,  
        map: mapa,        
        title: titulo     
    };     
    if(icono!=''){   
        opcionesMarcador.icon = icono;    
    }      
    var marcador = new google.maps.Marker(opcionesMarcador);   
    objetosMarcadores1.push(marcador); 
    if(contenido!=''){         
        google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'click', function() {   
            infowindow.setContent(contenido);      
            infowindow.open(mapa,marcador);  
        });      
    }   
}    
function agregarRuta(origen, destino) {  
    var request = {       
        origin: origen,    
        destination: destino,    
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING   
    };     
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) { 
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { 
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            resultadosRutas1.push(response);       
            var elementoDistancia = jQuery('.distancia');   
            if (elementoDistancia.length > 0) {        
                elementoDistancia.text(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);      
            }   
            var elementoTiempo = jQuery('.tiempo');   
            if (elementoTiempo.length > 0) {       
                elementoTiempo.text(response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);  
            }           
        }  
    });   
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    marcadores1[0] = new Array(-30.745418, -59.580419, '', '', '');
    rutas1[0] = new Array('Suipacha 929, rosario', '-30.745418,-59.580419');
    inicializarMapa(1, marcadores1, 6, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, false, rutas1);


    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/arco.png', -30.744722, -59.581353, '<p>Arco de Acceso</p>');
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/izquierda.png', -30.74024, -59.611314, '<p>Ruta de Acceso</p>');
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/izquierda.png', -30.73894, -59.623577, '<p>Ruta de Acceso</p>');
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/curva.png', -30.737456, -59.633469, '<p>Ruta de Acceso</p>');
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/dummy.png', -30.737628, -59.633958);
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/dummy.png', -30.737871, -59.634306);
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/dummy.png', -30.738106, -59.63468);
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/dummy.png', -30.738161, -59.635031);
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/izquierda.png', -30.738129, -59.635378, '<p>Ruta de Acceso</p>');
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/puente.png', -30.737838, -59.638017, '<p>Puente Rojo</p>');
    var marcadorCabana = agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/dummy.png', -30.737718, -59.640431);

    //Una vez que tenemos todos los iconitos, los unimos con polilíneas
    var polyOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#292b9c',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 5
    }
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
    poly.setMap(mapa1);
    for (i = 0; i < objetosMarcadores1.length; i++) {
        var marcador = objetosMarcadores1[i];
        var path = poly.getPath();
        path.push(marcador.getPosition());
    }

    //Agregamos por último la cabaña y la estación de servicio
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/cabana-verde.png', -30.738018, -59.640469, '<p>Cabañas Los Fardos</p>', true);
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/estacion.png', -30.737764, -59.641375, '<p>Estación de Servicio OIL</p>');
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/plaza.png', -30.740434, -59.644414, '<p>Plaza Principal</p>');
    agregarIcono('http://www.cabanaslosfardos.com.ar/plantillas/losFardos/imagenes/comoLlegar/puerto.png', -30.734422, -59.640745, '<p>Puerto</p>');
});
```